# queryExecute ColdFusion syntax vs Railo/Lucee syntax

Tags: coldfusion, railo, coldfusion-11, lucee

I have a bunch of code that has been written against a Railo server.  We are now trying to move some of that code over to a CF11 box and a Lucee box.

I have been using queryExecute like this:

```
rt = queryExecute(
        sql = 'select *
               from translation
               where    translationID = :translationID
                 and    translatedStr = :translatedStr'
    ,   params = {translationID: arguments.translationID
                , translatedStr: arguments.translatedStr}
    ,   options= {datasource: application.ds}
);
```

I was under the impression that the syntax was the same on CF11 but I am getting an error :

```
Parameter validation error for the QUERYEXECUTE function.
A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement as a parameter, 
although it can accept expressions. For example, QUERYEXECUTE(d=a*b) is not acceptable.
```

The above executeQuery works fine on Lucee.  I am going to need to go through the whole code base and make it work on both CF11 AND on Lucee.

Can someone, who is more familiar with ACF, tell me what is the best way to do this. It appears that ACF is having trouble with the param names. If I remove `sql =` and `params =` that takes away some of the problem, although I like the readability of having them named.  Also it appears that ACF doesn't like `translationID: arguments.translationID` and wants me to change it too `translationID = arguments.translationID`.  I just want to make sure that there isn't something I am missing before I go through the time consuming process of making all the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your parameters need to be in the form of a structure to include the value (and query param if you so choose).

Try this:

```
rt = queryExecute(
    "select *
      from translation
      where translationID = :translationID
          and translatedStr = :translatedStr",
    {
          translationID: {value: arguments.translationID},
          translatedStr: {value: arguments.translatedStr}
    },
    {datasource: application.ds}
);
```

Comment: Ok. My dev environment for ACF was giving me issues so I jumped the gun. When I get a chance I'll recheck what could be going wrong and update my answer. If someone else gets to it, I'll remove my answer since it apparently stands as wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Now that I think of it, have you tried removing "sql", "params" and "options" and just passing them implicitly? I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it works.  Problem is that means I have to change a LOT of code and before I do that I'd like to know if there are different parameter names and ACF and in Lucee.  I can pass them implicity but would prefer, if possible, to have them named.  But if I can't name them because ACT and Lucee don't name them the same I will HAVE to do it implicitly.  Thanks for your help Tony

Answer (score 1):

Well the error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

> A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement
>   as a parameter,  although it can accept expressions. For example,
>   QUERYEXECUTE(d=a*b) is not acceptable.

And you have this:

```
queryExecute(
        name = value
    ,   name = value
    ,   name= value
)
```

Which the error message says isn't allowed.

You just need to get rid of the names of your args. In-built CFML functions don't work like that. It's a compat bug in Lucee that it *does* support this.

Comment: Ugh I was afraid that was going to be the case.  We prefer, for readability, to have all the arguments named but if it doesn't work I guess we don't have  choice.  Thanks Adam

Comment: Well no CFML built-in function has ever allowed this, so I'm surprised you're only just running into this now.  it is definitely aberrant behaviour in (Railo's) `queryExecute()` that allows it. Unless Railo/Lucee have drifted even further away from standard CFML and allow this in general?

Comment: Isn't writeDump a built in function?  because `writeDump(var=var1, label='my var1')` has always worked.  I guess I totally missing something here.  Granted it doesn't matter as I have started going through and removing the argument names.

Comment: things get tricky in ColdFusion with `writeDump()`, `writelog()` and `throw()`, because whilst they look like functions, they do not behave thus. Try `result = writeDump(something)` for example. I have no idea what sort of construct they are, other than perhaps "parser gimmickery". On Railo and Lucee, they *are* functions, albeit seem to behave differently to normal built-in functions. Neither ColdFusion nor Railo/Lucee are doing the user any favours by implementing stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks Adam, pretty helpful!  Always learn a lot reading your stuff. Not that it helps with the frustration in the way the implementations differ between Adobe and Lucee.